# Notepad++ Perl Multi-line comment syntax highlighting

Tags: notepad++, perl

Is there a way to set notepad++ to highlight a Perl multi-line comment block as comments (currently there is no highlighting - it's black on white).

The type of comment I am talking about is of the form:

```
=comment
This is a comment
=cut
```

If there is a more proper Perl multi-line comment syntax, lmk =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Settings > Style Configurator, then select Perl from the language pane and POD (Plain Old Documentation) from the style pane and change the color there. I just tried this and it works for me.